# Shift + Delete (Permanent Deletion Of File/Folder): Mac Equivalent

Tags: keyboard, macos, trash

In Windows permanently deleting a file or folder without sending it to the recycle bin, is achieved by selecting that file or folder in Desktop or Windows explorer and then depressing the keyboard shortcut:

**Shift + Delete**

This is particularly useful for sensitive information.

Is there a keyboard shortcut equivalent within OS X that deletes files or folders permanently before they are disposed of in the trash.